# Google API Uncaught exception when use gapi.load

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin, google-developers-console, google-api-js-client

When I used this type of initialization:

```
var auth2;
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
}).then(function(){
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get()); //now this always returns correctly        
    });
});
```

I got the following error:

```
uncaught exception: gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Missing required parameter 'client_id'  (unknown)
TypeError: auth2 is undefined
```

But if I initialized using meta tag

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

That works, but **auth2.isSignedIn.get()** gave me inconsistent values.

How can I solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You may have included the below line of code to display Google's Sign In button.

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

If so, remove that from your html page and check if you are still getting error in console.

Comment: But that does not solve the issue at hand. Google Docs indicates that you add that class. So if it is removed, your CSS component for the button will not render

Comment: You need to add button on your own.

Comment: Google patterns. You should ensure when you use their auth methods to sign in, you use their buttons and logo for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Krishna's answer, specifically, you want to remove the `data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>` section, then create a [custom button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button):

```
<div id="my-signin2"></div>
<script>
    function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
    });
    }
</script>
```

As my sign-in is [handled server-side](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) I've added another jquery function to redirect to my backend flow, but you can adjust accordingly:

```
    <script>
    $('#my-signin2').click(function() {
        // if your sign in is handled by your backend:
        location.href = "/signin";

        // signInCallback defined in step 6.
        // auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(signInCallback);
    });
</script>
```